# Liferay Search Container pagination issue: When click on next or page no 2 it will redirect to default render method

Tags: pagination, liferay, searchcontainer

Liferay Search Container pagination issue: When we click on next or page no 2 it will redirect to default render method and default jsp is called.

I also searched Liferay community forums and they suggested to use iteratorURL or

```
<% PortletURL urlPaginator=renderResponse.createActionURL();
urlPaginator.setParameter("param1", value1);
urlPaginator.setParameter("param2",value2); %>

<liferay-ui:search-container iteratorURL="<%=urlPaginator%>">
```

I didn't get clear idea of how to use it and implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your iteration url, add jspPage param and give the jsp page value to it(Apparently the same page that the search container exists)

Comment: jsp page param or jsp page value ? any eg

Comment: try this `<liferay-portlet:renderURL varImpl="iteratorURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/yourpage.jsp" />          
</liferay-portlet:renderURL`

Comment: It worked but without specifying  value="your jsp page name"....As  if  I write <portlet:param name="(render name specified on @RenderMapping)" value=" (render params specified on @RenderMapping)"